# Complex conjugate of hydrogen ground state wave function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, hydrogen, complex-numbers

For hydrogen atom ground state
we know [image].

I want to know the complex conjugate of [image].

Comment: If $a$ is a real number (which it looks like it is), then the function is its own complex conjugate.  Complex conjugation involves reversing the sign of the imaginary part of something.  If that something is entirely real, then you get the same result back after conjugation.

Comment: The isn't a physics question. It's a math question. And it's elementary for anyone dealing with quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the formula you gave is real, the complex conjugate is the same as the wave function itself.

Comment: you mean for real number, the the complex conjugate is the same as it self?

Comment: yes that's exactly what I meant

Answer (score 1):

$$r=a+0i$$

$r$ is a Real number. Its complex conjugate is $r^*$:

$$r^*=a-0i$$

Obviously $r=r^*(=a)$.

And for the hydrogen atom, all $\psi_{n,0,0}$ are Real functions (all $s$ orbitals, not just the ground state $1s$).

Answer (score 0):

Since r is the radial Component of Spherical Coordinates : r>0 always positive and real Ψ*(r)=Ψ(r) (a,π are constants).

Comment: Well $r$ can be 0 as well, so it should be $r\geq0$.